# Inherting from Protocols in Python

Tags: python, mypy

Are there any benefits in inheriting from Protocols in Python?

eg.

```py
class SampleProtocol(Protocol):
    def do_something(self) -> int:
      ...
    
class Sample(SampleProtocol):
    def do_something(self) -> int:
        return 10
```

or should `Sample` just be a class that implements the Protocol without explicitly inheriting from it?

Answer (score 7):

Another advantage, according to the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation), is

> type checkers can statically verify that the class actually implements the protocol correctly.

That is, it can warn you if `Sample` doesn't have a conforming `do_something` method.

Comment: Exactly! If you *intend* that a class follow a particular protocol, then saying so in your code (a) is self-documenting for future readers of your code, and (b) allows the compiler to *check* that your intentions are met.

Answer (score 0):

`Sample` can just implement the required method. There is no intent for the protocol to be part of a class's MRO; it is for static type-checking only.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation looking at the pep it looks like it's a solid way of using protocols.

Comment: The question is not whether you can do it without inheritation, but the question is whether there are benefits in still using inheritation anyway. You do not really answer that.